# Why does Sabriel remark that "Touchstone" is a fool's name?

Tags: names, old-kingdom

In Garth Nix's book *Sabriel*, the titular character discovers a statue of a man. She is able to reanimate the man, she asks his name, and he replies "Touchstone." She replies something along the lines of "Touchstone? That's a fool's name." (I don't have the book with me so I can't quote it exactly.)

It is made obvious that it's not the man's original name, and it is also obviously (in both the book's world and ours) a dictionary word and not a "real" name... but why is it a *fool's name* specifically? Granted, dictionary words are not common as names, but it's not unheard of, and arguably "Touchstone" is a reasonably serious-sounding word to use.

Is there some in-world reason to say this? Given the book's fantasy trappings, is there a real-world cultural or historical reason that a fool would have or choose a word as a name?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is a little play on words happening here it seems; I think Sabriel isn't claiming the name itself is a foolish name, nor is she calling Touchstone himself unwise or imprudent (a literal fool).

Instead, she's referring to the second definition of the word: *[a court jester](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jester)*. Many of the royal courts throughout history employed jesters for variety of entertainment: music, singing, and storytelling to name a few.

[Touchstone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchstone_(As_You_Like_It)) is the court jester in Shakespeare's play *[As You Like It](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As_You_Like_It)*.

The passage from the book makes it clear she's definitely referring to the word "fool" to mean "jester":

> “Touchstone?” asked Sabriel. That sounded familiar, but she couldn’t place it for a moment. “Touchstone? But that’s **a jester’s name**, a fool’s name. Why call you that?”
>
> <sub>*Sabriel* - Chapter 14</sub>

Comment: AHA. So I *did* have the vague notion that she might have meant "it is the kind of name a clown would have," but I was missing the Shakespeare reference to really make sense of it. Thank you.

Comment: @detly - In fact, there was a "Shakespeare" of sorts in Ancelstierre, and while I don't know whether she wrote *As You Like It*, she probably wrote something similar.

Comment: Yes, Charlotte Breakespear, who is obviously the Ancelstierran version of Shakespeare. Since she wrote *The Three Noble Kinswoman*, I would bet on a play called *As I Like It* with a character called something similar to Touchstone.

Comment: I had always assumed it had in-world associations as a jester's name but didn't realise it got those from our world – clearly need to brush up my Shakespeare...